# Looping through an Array in C with no output

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
int tiles[9];
int counter=0;
int i=1;
while (counter<8)
{
    tiles[counter]=i;
    counter=counter+1;
    i=i+1;
    }
int running_total=0;
int current_number;
printf(tiles);

return 0;
}
```

But I get no output, what is my problem? I'm new to C so I appreciate any comments/criticism.

Edit: I do get an output, but it's a smily face...

Comment: You're not filling the last element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you want to print a number, you need a format string.
2. If you want to print an array, you need to loop through it.

   ```
   int i;
   for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(tiles)/ sizeof(tiles[0]); ++i)
       printf("%d ", tiles[i]); // << added a space for Dietrich Epp :)
   ```